# Is it possible to have multiple rules for different domains in CSP header?

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy

Is it possible to have multiple rules for different domains? For example, I want to combine following rules for `script-src`

- `'self'` is allowed to `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval`
- `domain1.net` and `domain2.net` are allowed to load
- `unsafe-domain.net` is known to be unsafe, but has to be included anyway, so only do it with hash check `sha512-...`